# Set default debug project in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I'm building a .NET app, and since last time I launched it something changed, and now it launches my Webservice instead of my main project when I debug (or even release). 
I'd just like to replace the default debug target by my main project, how can I do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to right click the project and hit "Set as default target"

More details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1awth7y.aspx)

Comment: Wow okay I'm bad haha. It works fine, thanks a lot !